# gud: highlight breakpoints with custom debugger

Tags: gud, golang

I use go-dlv to debug Go programs. This package is very simple and relies on standard gud functionality (https://github.com/benma/go-dlv.el/blob/master/go-dlv.el)

One thing that I found missing is highlighting of breakpoints.

Is there any easy way to customize GUD to enable this feature? If not I would appreciate any advice how to implement it. I am fairly new to customizing emacs and do not know where to start. Thanks in advance.